# How to get android source

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to get eclair sources as described here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html but getting into trouble after executing a command:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b android-2.1

fatal: unable to connect to android.git.kernel.org:
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own links states that the URL for `repo init` should be the https version. Try:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using an out of date server.  With the kernel.org attack a few months back, google moved android to one of their own servers.  To get the sources, do:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.1
```